# How to add custom map and custom data to Highmaps?

Tags: dictionary, highcharts, highmaps

I am struggling with including a custom map with custom data into Highmaps. I am sure it's a pretty dumb thing, but I just can't find any examples and explanations on the web.

I have a JSON file with the data, and a GeoJSON file with the map. So, it could look like this:

```
        $(function () 
        {
            $.getJSON('http://xxx/data/P_.json', function (data)
            {
                // Initiate the chart
                $('#container').highcharts('Map',
                {
                    series : [
                    {
                        data : data,
                        mapData: 'http://www/data/countries.geojson',
                        joinBy: ['Name', 'Countries'],
                    }]
                });
            });
        });
```

But something is quite obviously wrong. How do I add then the custom mapData?

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a instruction about how to create custom geoJSON: http://www.highcharts.com/docs/maps/custom-geojson-maps

In 9. there is link to jsFiddle that show how geoJSON file should be parsed to be used by Highcharts as mapData: http://jsfiddle.net/highcharts/xbzxfx2L/

```
$('#run').click(function () {     
    var geojson = $.parseJSON($('#geojson').val());

    // Initiate the chart
    $('#container').slideDown().highcharts('Map', {
        series: [{
            mapData: geojson
        }]
    });    
});
```

Comment: Yes, I am well aware of these, and have tried my geojson there. However, I still don't see how both files (Json and GeoJson) are being included. I've tried it like this, but it doesn't work: `$(function () 
{
var geojson = $.parseJSON($('http://bluedot.world/data/P_per_capita_limit.geojson').val());

$.getJSON('http://bluedot.world/data/P_.json', function (data)
{
// Initiate the chart
$('#container').highcharts('Map', 
{
series : [
{
data : data,
mapData: geojson,
joinBy: ['Name', 'Countries_']
}]
});
});
});`

Comment: You should get geoJSON like you would have done with JSON file. See this demo: http://jsfiddle.net/gh/get/jquery/1.9.1/highslide-software/highcharts.com/tree/master/samples/maps/demo/geojson/ (Additionally: if you need to use two getJSON calls - place one inside the other to be sure that files will be fetched on time)

Comment: Ok, thanks. That helped. I finally went with this one: `$.getJSON('http://xxx/data/P_per_capita_limit.geojson', function (geojson) { $.getJSON('http://xxx/data/P_.json', function (data) {`